# How to zoom to text in VIM via shortcut?

Tags: key-bindings, font

I want to zoom in VIM, like Sublime text or Atom, using `CTRL +` & `CTRL -` and `CTRL 0` for reset to default font-size.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using vim in a terminal you can simply use its zoom shortcuts. For Gnome-Terminal this is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>. In others it may be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>.

Also there are several plugins out there for this purpose. e.x: https://github.com/drmikehenry/vim-fontsize

As an alternative you can define your own functions like this one from [vim.wika.com](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_font_size_quickly)

```
let s:pattern = '^\(.* \)\([1-9][0-9]*\)$'
let s:minfontsize = 6
let s:maxfontsize = 16
function! AdjustFontSize(amount)
  if has("gui_gtk2") && has("gui_running")
    let fontname = substitute(&guifont, s:pattern, '\1', '')
    let cursize = substitute(&guifont, s:pattern, '\2', '')
    let newsize = cursize + a:amount
    if (newsize >= s:minfontsize) && (newsize <= s:maxfontsize)
      let newfont = fontname . newsize
      let &guifont = newfont
    endif
  else
    echoerr "You need to run the GTK2 version of Vim to use this function."
  endif
endfunction

function! LargerFont()
  call AdjustFontSize(1)
endfunction
command! LargerFont call LargerFont()

function! SmallerFont()
  call AdjustFontSize(-1)
endfunction
command! SmallerFont call SmallerFont()
```

An then map two keys to `:LargerFont` and `:SmallerFont`

Comment: The functions work (on Ubuntu 16.04 running gVim 8.2).  Check for `has("gui_gtk2")` was removed in my `.vimrc`

Answer (score 2):

Apparat's answer works for gVim; if you're using Vim from within a Terminal, you will need to configure the terminal to change the font size.

For Xterm, I like to use:

```
XTerm*VT100.translations: #override \n\
    Ctrl <KeyPress> =:larger-vt-font() \n\
    Ctrl <KeyPress> -:smaller-vt-font()
```

In my `~/.Xdefaults` to change the font size with `CTRL +` and `CTRL -`.

Some terminals also respond to escape codes to set the font; for Xterm I've never been able to get that to work correctly, though...