# Increment or Decrement font in a neovim GUI?

Tags: neovim, font, neovim-qt

I have crawled around forums and didn't found an answer which suits my needs. I want to use Neovim in a GUI, but not being able to change the font size on the fly with a keypress is a complete dealbreaker.
So I will continue the tradition of asking: how do I quickly change the font in GUI Neovim? Specifically, I am trying to use nvim-qt, if that helps.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5804/how-to-zoom-to-text-in-vim-via-shortcut https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3093/how-can-i-change-the-font-size-in-gvim https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Change_guifont_to_see_more_of_your_file https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Change_font_size_quickly Also, about a half other people's vimrcs floating around github and all over the internet. Just take `&guifont` value; parse it; increment and write back.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I suspect we’ll end up closing this as a duplicate (and that’s not a bad thing—it helps others find the answers, too). In the meantime, another example: https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/vim/gvimrc

Comment: Ok. Frankly, having to parse the value of the variable is just ridiculous, but if it works it works. Thanks.

Comment: I don’t disagree, but fortunately it’s not difficult.

Comment: @Matt why don't you write such things as answer. Not every answer should be very elaborated.

Comment: @eyalkarni I think this is duplicate.